# How to relate to button created in SFML-IMGUI?

Tags: c++, sfml, imgui

Hello I want to create some buttons with SFML-IMGUI and after that relate to them in some way for example to change text. How can I do this? I dont see any ID attribute. I create button using this code.

```
ImGui::Begin("Button");
Button("Click me");
End();
```

I dont see any example in documentation :/

Comment: Isn't the point of imguis design that you do things inline? If you want the button to act on something, you need to reference it then and there where the button is created.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Imgui buttons don't use any id or callbacks. Instead, the `ImGui::Button("Clikc me")` will return a boolean which is true if the button was clicked. (here is an example)

```cpp
ImGui::Begin("window");

if (ImGui::Button("Click me")) {
    // onButtonClick();
}

ImGui::End();
```

for more read https://github.com/ocornut/imgui/tree/master/docs and see`imgui_demo.cpp` it has some better examples on how to use it.